# Unable to locate Android SDK in VSCode Terminal

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk

I have installed flutter, android SDK and VSCode, everything seems OK when I run
`flutter doctor` in the terminal, but when i run it from the terminal of VSCode it shows me this error 'Unable to locate Android SDK'

flutter doctor from main terminal
[image: flutter doctor from terminal]

flutter doctor from VSCode terminal
[image: flutter doctor from VSCode terminal]

Comment: I would set the path variable to include the folder of the file its looking for.

Comment: thanks, i have find the solution, its bqz my main shell is of type zsh and the shell in VSCode is of type bash so when I change it to zsh its working